# Add dark/light theme toggle storage returns true all time

Tags: reactjs, local-storage

I am trying to create dark/light mode toggle, however It doesn't seem to work when I refresh the page, it keeps being set to false, even though I change the theme. Why is it not remembering the true setting?

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import './style.css';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

export default function App() {
  const [darkMode, setDarkMode] = useState(false);

  function setTheme() {
    const dark = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('darkMode'));
    setDarkMode(dark);
    console.log(darkMode);
  }

  useEffect(setTheme);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (darkMode == true) {
      localStorage.setItem('darkMode', JSON.stringify(true));
      document.body.style.background = 'red';
      setDarkMode(true);
    } else {
      console.log(darkMode);
      localStorage.setItem('darkMode', JSON.stringify(false));
      document.body.style.background = 'black';
      setDarkMode(false);
    }
  }, [darkMode]);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello StackBlitz!</h1>
      <button onClick={() => setDarkMode(true)}>set to true</button>
      <button onClick={() => setDarkMode(false)}>set to false</button>

      <p>Start editing to see some magic happen :)</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of things:

1. Use any existing value for the initial state - make sure it's a boolean.
2. You are checking the value of local storage, whereas you really want to check the `darkMode` state value.
3. You don't need to update the state inside the effect

```js
// #1 use any existing value for the initial state
const initialState = localStorage.getItem("darkMode") === "true";
const [ darkMode, setDarkMode ] = useState(initialState);

useEffect(() => {
    // #2 check the state value here
    if (darkMode === true) {
      localStorage.setItem("darkMode", JSON.stringify(true))
      document.body.style.background = 'red'
      // #3 don't update state
      console.log('true!')
    } else {
      localStorage.setItem("darkMode", JSON.stringify(false))
      document.body.style.background = 'black'
      // #3 don't update state
      console.log('false')
    }
}, [darkMode])
```

Here's a playground: https://playcode.io/1008374

Comment: If user sets to red, and presses F5 then it still should be on red, but it keeps changing the value to black. How can this be done? I changed my OP, but my solution doesnt seem to work.

Comment: I updated my answer to use an existing value for the intial state.

Comment: Thanks, weird because I tried this before and I got errors but now it seems to work. And I read that localStorage can be only used in watchEffect

Comment: You only want to update localStorage inside an effect. You can usually read localStorage anywhere.